# Custom filters in angularJS expressions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I want to do a custom filter within .tpl.html file itself using AngularJS.

Following is my case,

#### Controller:

```
$scope.selectedFruits = [{'name': 'mango', 'color': 'yellow'}];

$scope.favouriteFruits = [{'name': 'cherry', 'color': 'red'}, 
                          {'name': 'papaya', 'color': 'yellow'}];

$scope.fruits = [{'name': 'apple', 'color': 'red'}, 
                 {'name': 'mango', 'color': 'yellow'}, 
                 {'name': 'guava', 'color': 'green'},
                 {'name': 'grape', 'color': 'black'},
                 {'name': 'cherry', 'color': 'red'}, 
                 {'name': 'papaya', 'color': 'yellow'},
                 {'name': 'orange', 'color': 'orange'}];
```

#### Template

```
<select name="fruit" class="form-control" 
        ng-model="model.selectedFruits" 
        ng-options="fruit as fruit.name 
                    for fruit in filteredFruits)"/>
</select>
```

Where filteredFruits should be filtered like this:

```
filteredFruits = (fruits not in (selectedFruits and favouriteFruits))
```

How can I achieve the above case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular's built in `filter` filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

From the docs:

> `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`

`expression` can be a function that returns `true` for the items that should be included, so in your controller:

```
$scope.filterFunction = (fruit)->
  (fruit not in (selectedFruits and favouriteFruits))
```

Then your template:

```
<select name="fruit" 
        class="form-control" 
        ng-model="model.selectedFruits" 
        ng-options="fruit as fruit.name 
                    for fruit in fruits | filter:filterFunction)"/>
```

[Plunker demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/s5RnmTtz88ubFkHVGXQJ?p=preview)